# How can we get project version from pom.xml in assembly plugin

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

How can we get project version from pom.xml in assembly plugin, as {version} and {project.version} seem not working in assembly-plugin xml

```
<id>zip</id>
<includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>

<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>  
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/root/config</directory>
        <outputDirectory>{version}/config</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/common/lib</directory>
        <outputDirectory>{version}/bin/JAVA</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

Comment: Could you please add your `assembly-plugin.xml`? What are trying to do with the version number in the assembly plugin?

Comment: Trying to create a folder inside target zip file, with name as project version: 


<formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
 
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/root/config</directory>
            <outputDirectory>{version}/config</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/common/lib</directory>
            <outputDirectory>{version}/bin/JAVA</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>

Comment: `${project.version}` does not work?

Comment: No, both {version} and {project.version} did not work

Comment: Did you put the `$` in front of `${project.version}`?

Comment: ${project.version} worked, Thanks Meier. such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

${project.version} worked, was missing $